# How to set the value of sublist field on current line based on other sublist value on same line. I am using client script

Tags: suitescript2.0

Creating Client Script wherein as user enters the account no# on expense line of bill ensuring that for certain accounts amortization field value is set to null on saving the line (no mattter what user enters) and for all other accounts keep as is

```
function validateLine(scriptContext) {
    var bill = scriptContext.currentRecord;
    var expAccountVal = bill.getCurrentSublistText({
         sublistId: 'expense',
         fieldId: 'account',});
    var expAmortSchVal = bill.getCurrentSublistText({
     sublistId: 'expense',
     fieldId: 'amortizationSched',});

    if (expAccountVal == 'Prepaid Expenses and Other')
        { 
        bill.setCurrentSublistText({
            sublistId: 'expense',
            fieldId: 'amortizationSched',
            text: ' ',
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a fieldChanged function rather than a validate line function. Also, I would recommend using "getCurrentSublistValue" rather than text. It's a lot more sustainable in case you end up changing account names. You're like 90% of the way there... Also, remember to refresh cache whenever you test out client scripts! For anyone else reading, having 'ignoreFieldChange: true' was perfect. You'll get error messages if you don't include that piece. NetSuite has a very good article on this here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_157375587585.html